# How to draw a gamemap in console?

Tags: java, console, matrix

Im working on a game, developed in console  and I have a question of how to draw a map like this in the java console, im using Eclipse and I'm new in java: My game board is a matrix. Points are spaces in the matrix, and 'o' are like walls. ¿Can anyone help me to get something like this???  Thanks

ooooooo..............ooooooo..............ooooooo..............ooooooo
ooooooo..............ooooooo..............ooooooo..............ooooooo
ooooooo..............ooooooo..............ooooooo..............ooooooo
ooooooo..............ooooooo..............ooooooo..............ooooooo
..................................................................................................
  .................................................................................................. ..................................................................................................
ooooooo..............ooooooo..............ooooooo..............ooooooo
ooooooo..............ooooooo..............ooooooo..............ooooooo ooooooo..............ooooooo..............ooooooo..............ooooooo ooooooo..............ooooooo..............ooooooo..............ooooooo
..................................................................................................
  .................................................................................................. ..................................................................................................
ooooooo..............ooooooo..............ooooooo..............ooooooo
ooooooo..............ooooooo..............ooooooo..............ooooooo ooooooo..............ooooooo..............ooooooo..............ooooooo ooooooo..............ooooooo..............ooooooo..............ooooooo
..................................................................................................
  .................................................................................................. ..................................................................................................
ooooooo..............ooooooo..............ooooooo..............ooooooo
ooooooo..............ooooooo..............ooooooo..............ooooooo ooooooo..............ooooooo..............ooooooo..............ooooooo ooooooo..............ooooooo..............ooooooo..............ooooooo

Comment: Who in this millennium would play a console based game?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Fans of [nethack](http://www.nethack.org/), perhaps?

Comment: @Andrew Thompson - apparently quite a few according to this: http://alt.org/nethack/

Answer (score 1):

You can use a matrix of `integer`s or `enum`s and draw the matrix as a bunch of characters.

Simple example, given `Tile[][] matrix`:

```
for(int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
   for(int col = 0; col < matrix[0].length; col++) {
      System.out.print(matrix[row][col].getCharacter());
   }
   System.out.println();
}
```